# Power BI RestAPI get datasources returns empty

Tags: powerbi

I populated my Power BI cloud service with the `Human Resources Sample`, and then I try to get the datasources information using the Rest API of the Power BI service, but it always return an empty list. Do I need to do any configurations to get these information? Thanks!

Request:
`https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/datasources`
Response:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "http://wabi-west-europe-d-primary-redirect.analysis.windows.net/v1.0/myorg/$metadata#datasources",
  "value": []
}
```

Comment: Are you running this as yourself, the Dataset owner? And is the dataset in your "My Workspace"?  Because that API is for My Workspace.

Comment: Yes, the dataset is in the "My Workspace" and I run it as the Dataset Owner, directly on the site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-datasources